# Why is TRD failing the payouts?

Tags: baking, error, rewards, tezos-reward-distributor

I'm running the tezos rewards distributor for the cycle payouts. The command is:
python3 src/main.py -C 386 -V on -s -R -5 -M 4,
some payouts are successful - bravo to the authors.
But the 2/3 of payouts failed with the error:
Error, response ->[{"kind":"permanent","id":"node.prevalidation.oversized_operation","size":34171,"max_size":32768}]
How do I fix it to run failed payments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the latest [v9.0 version](https://github.com/tezos-reward-distributor-organization/tezos-reward-distributor/releases/tag/v9.0)?

Comment: yes, i noticed the update, thank you. retrying payouts with a new version, i will submit results. also, it seems to me, there might be some problem with my local tezos rpc node, because this error is listed as an rpc error in the official tezos docs

Comment: Open a bug report on TRD's github. An oversized operation means too many transactions where attempted to be batched together, which is something TRD tries to do.

Comment: everything appears to run smoothly after update. waiting for the next cycle ;)